# QT Crashing When I Set Char Pointer to an Int Value

Tags: c++, qt

I have a C++ Program running in QT that is crashing whenever I reach this line. I am debugging it and trying to figure out why it is crashing, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //set central widget for the Main Window
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    //creation and attribution of slider
    slider = new QSlider();
    slider->resize(255, 20);
    slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    slider->setRange(0, 255); //0-255 is range we can read

    //layout with slider and lcd
    main_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    main_layout->addWidget(slider);

    //set layout to the widget inside MainWindow
    centralWidget->setLayout(main_layout);

    /*Connection Events*/
    //connection between the slider event and the transmission function
    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(transmitCmd(int)));
}
void MainWindow::transmitCmd(int value)
{
    //if value wasn't between 0-255, no transmission
    if(value < 0 || value > 255)
        return;

    char *buffer = NULL; //create a buffer to store value
    *buffer = value;
}
```

It crashes when I write *buffer = value. Not sure why this is happening and checked out other questions with setting char pointer to an int.

Comment: You do realize you are dereferencing a null pointer in the line `*buffer = value`. Allocate memory to the buffer before you assign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, because you are attempting to write data to a `NULL` pointer. A `char*` holds an assignable address to some memory location.

So when you declare your `buffer` variable, you are not automatically allocating buffer to store data, it is effectively an empty link.

When you try to write data to a `char*`, you are writing to memory address zero, which results in an access violation exception.

To avoid this exception, you can allocate memory using the `new` operator which will also provide a base address for your variable like the following:

```
char *buffer = (char*) new int(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer must point to existed content, then can be dereferenced. If the pointer is NULL, dereference will crash.

```
char buffer[1] = {'\0'}; //create a buffer to store value
*buffer = value & 0xFF;
```